# Exclamation point with data

Tags: moto-x, t-mobile

Wifi works fine. Making and receiving calls work fine. BUT, no data. The data symbol is the bars, with an exclamation point. The phone won't join the data network, but everything else works fine. What is wrong?

Answer (score 1):

This took a lot of searching, and 10 phone reps before one could help. The default APN protocol was wrong: APN protocol: IPv4/IPv6.

It wasn't set to use both. That one little change to the APN fixed the problem, and now I have data again.

```
Miraflor A: 
Name: T-Mobile US LTE
APN: fast.t-mobile.com
Proxy: 
Port: 
Username: 
Password: 
Server: 
MMSC: http://mms.msg.eng.t-mobile.com/mms/wapenc
MMS proxy: 
MMS port: 
MMS protocol: WAP 2.0
MCC: 310
MNC: 260
Authentication type: 
APN type: OR Internet+MMS
APN protocol: IPv4/IPv6
APN roaming protocol: IPv4
Enable/disable APN: 
Bearer: Unspecified
```

> You: there's no MMS protocol
>
> Miraflor A: You mean there's no info on the MMS protocol or that settings is not available at all?
>
> You: not available
>
> Miraflor A: Thanks!